# Openfire bouncing message back to sender

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am making a  Openfire plugin for send the message from server to client.

A client send a message with a custom extension without to attribute because the plugin will decide reciepants.But the Openfire is bouncing it back to sender.How to make this approach work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openfire is an XMPP server. The XMPP server defines how the server should [process a message without a 'to' attribute](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-10.3).

A common approach is to create a (server-sided), addressable entity (for instance, by having your plugin create a Component). Your clients could then send the message to that component.